# Exit / stop Array2D.initBased early

Tags: arrays, f#, exit, break

How is it possible to exit early / break out of / stop an array creation in F# (in this case, of `Array2D.initBased`)?

*Remark:* `dic` is a `Dictionary<,>()` whose value is an object that has a method named `someMethod` that takes two `int` parameters.

```
let arr = Array2D.initBased 1 1 width height (fun x y -> 
    let distinctValues = dic |> Seq.map (fun (KeyValue(k,v)) -> v.someMethod x y) |> Set.ofSeq
        match distinctValues.count with
        | dic.Count ->
            // do something
            // exit array creation here, because I do not need arr any more if v.someMethod x y produced distinct values for each dic value
        | _ -> 
            // do something else
```

Comment: Your sample does not really make much sense to me. You take `dic`, sort it and then create a set? But set ignores the order, so the value `distinctValues` will be the same for every `x, y` arguments. This means that you could just check the property *before* you start constructing the array. So, I think there is something wrong...

Comment: `someMethod` uses a property of object `v` besides x and y, which is different for each value of `dic`'s value, i.e. `v`, resulting in a possibly different `distinctValues`. This way, transforming `Dictionary<,>()` `dic` into `Set` `distinctValues` makes sense.

Comment: I would understand it if it used `Seq.map`, but not with `Seq.sortBy` - even if the result of `someMethod` differs for each iteration (which it does), you are only using this to re-order the elements - but ordering does not matter if you turn that into a set at the end.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Oh, I see! Makes sense now :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky question - I don't think there is any function that lets you do this easily. I think the best option is probably to define your own higher-order function (implemented using not very elegant recursion) that hides the behavior.

The idea would be to define `tryInitBased` that behaves as `initBased` but the user-provided function can return option (to indicate failure) and the function returns option (either successfully created array or `None`):

```
/// Attempts to initialize a 2D array using the specified base offsets and lengths.
/// The provided function can return 'None' to indicate a failure - if the initializer
/// fails for any of the location inside the array, the construction is stopped and
/// the function returns 'None'.
let tryInitBased base1 base2 length1 length2 f = 
  let arr = Array2D.createBased base1 base2 length1 length2 (Unchecked.defaultof<_>)
  /// Recursive function that fills a specified 'x' line
  /// (returns false as soon as any call to 'f' fails, or true)
  let rec fillY x y = 
    if y < (base2+length2) then
      match f x y with
      | Some v -> 
          arr.[x, y] <- v
          fillY x (y + 1)
      | _ -> false
    else true
  /// Recursive function that iterates over all 'x' positions
  /// and calls 'fillY' to fill individual lines
  let rec fillX x = 
    if x < (base1+length1) then 
      if fillY x base2 then fillX (x + 1)
      else false
    else true
  if fillX base1 then Some arr else None
```

Then you can keep your code pretty much the same, but replace `initBased` with `tryInitBased` and return `None` or `Some(res)` from the lambda function.

I also posted the function to [F# snippets](http://fssnip.net/lJ) with a nicer formatting.

Comment: As an F# neophyte I am still digesting the beauty of your solution. Brilliant.