# How to convert an Array2D with option int elements to Array2D with int elements

Tags: arrays, f#, option-type

I am trying to convert Array2D `optionArr` with option int elements to Array2D `arr` with int elements:

```
let arr =
    optionArr
    |> Array2D.map (fun x -> 
        match Option.toArray x with
        | [| |] -> -1
        | [| v |] -> v)
```

However, Visual Studio 2013 underlines everything starting from `Array2D.map ...` until `... -> v)` with red and says:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a  
    int [,] option -> 'a
but given a  
    'b [,] -> 'c [,]  
The type 'int [,] option' does not match the type ''a [,]'
```

I have been trying to "fix" my code but I no idea what I am doing wrong nor what the above error message alludes to.

**EDIT**

I applied [Reed Copsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21943311/3334662) (which itself uses [Marcin's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942636/how-to-convert-an-array2d-with-option-int-elements-to-array2d-with-int-elements/21942981#21942981)), yet still got the above error message when I realised that the message clearly states that `Array2D` `arr` is of type `int [,] option` and not `int option [,]`. Applying the same logic my corrected code is as follows:

```
let arr = defaultArg optionArr (Array2D.zeroCreate 0 0)
```

[`defaultArg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340463.aspx) seems to be quite useful for treating `Option` values as 'normal' ones.

Comment: How do you declare `optionArr`? Is it really 2D array or jagged array?

Comment: It is not a jagged array, but a 2D one. For declaration, see Tomas Petricek's answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919785/exit-stop-array2d-initbased-early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Marcin's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21942981/65358) works fine.  This can also be done a bit more simply using [defaultArg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340463.aspx) directly:

```
// Create our array
let optionArr = Array2D.create 10 10 (Some(1))

let noneToMinusOne x = defaultArg x -1
let result = optionArr |> Array2D.map noneToMinusOne
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let arr optionArr =
    optionArr
    |> Array2D.map (fun x -> 
        match x with
        | Some(y) -> y
        | None -> -1)
```

usage

```
let getOptionArr =
    Array2D.create 10 10 (Some(1))

let result = arr getOptionArr
```

Comment: You could just do `|> Array2D.map (fun x -> defaultArg x -1)` too  - See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340463.aspx